# css showing images twice oppose to once?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I have this css code that shows the photos twice, its weird, is there a better I can write this, the links are used to vote using jQuery?

css code:

```
a.vote_up, a.vote_down {
        display:inline-block;
    background-repeat:none;
    background-position:center;
        height:30px;
    width:30px;
    margin-left:4px;
    text-indent:-900%;
}

a.vote_up {
    background:url("images/uparrow.png");
}

a.vote_down {
    background:url("images/downarrow.png");
}
```

html:

```
<span class='vote_buttons' id='vote_buttons<?php echo $row['id']; ?>'>
    <a href='javascript:;' class='vote_up' id='<?php echo $row['id']; ?>'>Vote Up!</a>
    <a href='javascript:;' class='vote_down' id='<?php echo $row['id']; ?>'>Vote Down!</a>
</span>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding `background-repeat: no-repeat;` to your a.vote_up and a.vote_down. By default backgrounds will be repeated.

Comment: That should be "background-repeat", not just "repeat".

Comment: Thanks  a lot. It helped me to resolve the issue. The below mentioned link was also add-on to it: http://www.css3.info/preview/background-size/

Answer (score 2):

By using `background`, you are overwriting the repeat and position settings from the first style definition.

Use `background-image` instead:

```
a.vote_up, a.vote_down {
    display:inline-block;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;  //changed to no-repeat
    background-position:center;  
    height:30px;
    width:30px;
    margin-left:4px;
    text-indent:-900%;
}
                  // background-image to prevent overwrite 
a.vote_up {       //    of background-repeat & background-position
    background-image:url("images/uparrow.png"); 
}
a.vote_down {
    background-image:url("images/downarrow.png");
}
```

And the `background-repeat` should be `no-repeat`.